# How can I connect with Python to a subfolder in an Azure Container if I only have access to that folder?

Tags: python, azure, azure-storage

I have access to a specific folder in an Azure Blob Container and want to connect to it via Python. In Azure Storage Explorer I was able to set up that connection via selecting "ADLS Gen2 container or directory" as a Resource and then pasting the `sas_url`.

[image: Azure Storage Explorer Select Resource]

How can achieve the same with Python? It seems like `BlobServiceClient` and `ContainerClient` are not the right choice as I don't have access to the whole container but only that subfolder.

```
sas_url = "https://storageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/container/folder/subfolder?fancy_token"
```

Answer (score 1):

**I tried in my environment and got the below results:**

> How can I connect with Python to a subfolder in an Azure Container if I only have access to that folder?

You can use the below code if you need to access only the subfolder name.

**Code:**

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient

connect_str="<Your connection string>"
container_name="test"
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connect_str)
container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container_name)
for file in container_client.walk_blobs('folder1/', delimiter='/'):
    print(file.name)
```

**Output:**

The above code is executed successfully and it returns the subfolder name.

```
folder1/subfolder1/
folder1/subfolder2/
folder1/subfolder3/
```

[image]

If you need to access the subfolders with files you can use the below code:

**Code:**

```
    from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
    
    connect_str="<Your connection string>"
    container_name="test"
    blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connect_str)
    container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container_name)
    for  file  in  container_client.walk_blobs('folder1/subfolder1/', delimiter='/'):
    print(file.name)
```

**Output:**

The above code is executed successfully and returns the subfolder with the file name.

```
folder1/subfolder1/02-03-2023.html
folder1/subfolder1/03-03-2023.html
folder1/subfolder1/06-03-2023.html
folder1/subfolder1/06-03-2023.html
folder1/subfolder1/07-03-2023.html
folder1/subfolder1/07-03-2023.html
folder1/subfolder1/3-14-2023.html
```

[image]

**Reference:**
[Azure Storage Blobs client library for Python | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/overview/azure/storage-blob-readme?view=azure-python)